# How to insert my code into startForeground method Android

Tags: service

i want run my code into background, for example this loop, no matter:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=500; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Where Do I must insert this code?

MainActivity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

MyService contaise this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(0)
                .setContentTitle("My Awesome App")
                .setContentText("Doing some work...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(1337, notification);
```